# How to display a text file whose first line is displayed in uppercase, while the remaining lines are unchanged

Tags: shell, terminal

`tr a-z A-Z < items.txt`

The above command can convert the text file to UPPER CASE, but I want the command that converts the first line only, leaving the other lines untouched.

Comment: Using GNU sed: `sed '1s/.*/\U&/' items.txt`

Comment: or awk (any flavour): `awk 'NR == 1 {$0 = toupper($0)} 1' items.txt`

Answer (score 1):

Both of the commands given in the comments work.

[Shawn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9952196/shawn)'s solution:

```bash
$ echo -e 'one\ntwo\nthree' | sed '1s/.*/\U&/'
ONE
two
three
```

[glenn jackman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7552/glenn-jackman)'s solution:

```bash
$ echo -e 'one\ntwo\nthree' | awk 'NR == 1 {$0 = toupper($0)} 1'
ONE
two
three
```

Answer (score 0):

in `awk`, rule `#1` is that don't split unnecessary fields :

```
echo -e "one alpha apple\ntwo beta"    \
        " orange\nthree omicron durian" | 

{m,g}awk -F'^$' 'NF<NR || $_=toupper($_)'

ONE ALPHA APPLE
two beta orange
three omicron durian
```